# Suggest an irrational number from decimal one

Tags: numerics, approximation

I want to know is there any function in Mathematica that suggests a simple irrational number combination for decimal one?

For example, if I give 0.804738 then I get `(Sqrt[2] + 1)/3`.

(***EDIT***)

Or consider `1.301290284568573 = π/(Sqrt[2] + 1)`.

It seems for the first example `RootApproximant` gives the correct answer but for the second its answer is not useful at all.

Comment: Have you seen `RootApproximant`?

Comment: Thank you! This works for this number. But I suggest that, for example, 0.8185261683292934 should be related to sqrt[2] with simple relation.

Comment: I want a function that also predicts something like \pi, RootApproximant[\[Pi]] is not that.

Comment: `Pi*RootApproximant[1.30129028/Pi]`

Comment: [AskConstants](http://askconstants.org) is pretty amazing for this task.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try WolframAlpha

```
guess[x_]:=WolframAlpha["identify "<>ToString@x]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: There's no need for coding here: you can get the same effect by pressing `"="` twice and entering the number (or any W$\alpha$ query) directly.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it works.

Answer (score 6):

[AskConstants](http://askconstants.org) is extremely powerful. For the second example it gives several results:

```
(-1 + Sqrt[2]) \[Pi]
\[Pi] Tanh[ArcCosh[3]/4]
\[Pi] Sqrt[ModularLambda[I Sqrt[2]]]
(1 + Sqrt[2]) \[Pi] Sqrt[ModularLambda[2 I]]
1/2 \[Pi] Tanh[ArcCoth[2 + Sqrt[2]] + ArcCsch[1]]
```

[image]

Comment: While this package might be powerful, it is huge (!) and strangely organized. I read ` INSTALL.nb` and ` LOAD_ASKCONSTANTS.nb` twice, and still could not figure out how to install this thing.