# How to install AskConstants

Tags: packages

In one of the [posts](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/244369/9469) at mathematica.stackexchange I came across the [AskConstants](http://math.hawaii.edu/%7Edale/AskConstants/AskConstants.html) package. I am quite interested to try it, but after the downloading I realized that the package is huge: ~2GB in uncompressed form. Also, I found the installation instructions are very complicated. This made me thinking that the whole thing might be a virus. I would like to ask community if anyone has some experience with the package. Some assistance in installing would be great as well as some explanations on why this package is so huge.

Comment: It's an academic product, they likely don't have a [product manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_management) and are just geeks pushing out their own code. That said, there's no need to "install" anything: just download & unzip, then open `LOAD_ASKCONSTANTS.nb` and follow instructions: 1. execute `GetAskConstants[];`, then 2. execute `AskConstants[FontSize -> 14];` and deal with the interface.

Comment: I have never heard of this before, but reading [the author's paper](http://math.hawaii.edu/%7Edale/AskConstants/HowToHuntWildConstants.pdf), it mentions a similar Maple package whose full install size is 1TB, so that might just be the price paid for these techniques.

Comment: @Roman Thank you! If you are comfortable with this, you can make your comment a regular answer. Maybe some other users will find it useful.

Comment: @ChrisK Amazing! 1TB for a package, looks like they simply have a list of ALL possible numerical constants :)