# Finding closed form representations of floating point numbers?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics, numerical-value

Is there a trick to automatically recognize that ${-0.5771,1.2280}$ are approximately equal to `{-EulerGamma, Log[2 + Sqrt[2]]}`?

These were obtained by using `LinearModelFit` on data from this [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4705378/smallest-value-of-d-such-that-frac-left-sum-i-1d-i-p-right2-sum):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
prec = 800;
setPrec[expr_] := SetPrecision[expr, prec];
predict[p_?NumericQ] := 
  setPrec@Exp[-0.5843521872961219` + 1.228079016227338`*1/(p - 1)];
breakEven[p0_?NumericQ] := 
  Block[{},(*zeta[p]^2 lowers precision,hence use higher precision*)
   p = SetPrecision[p0, 1.5*prec];
   expr[d_] = 
    Zeta[p]^2/Zeta[2 p] - 
     2 HarmonicNumber[d, p]^2/HarmonicNumber[d, 2 p];
   df = D[expr, d];
   d /. FindRoot[expr[d], {d, predict[p]}, AccuracyGoal -> 1, 
     PrecisionGoal -> 5, WorkingPrecision -> prec - 1, 
     MaxIterations -> 50]];

startval = 2000;
rvals = Table[r, {r, startval, startval + 1}];
dvals = breakEven[1 + 1/#] & /@ rvals;

observedPlot = 
  ListPlot[{rvals, dvals}\[Transpose], 
   ScalingFunctions -> {Automatic, "Log"}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"r", "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(d\), \(*\)]\)"}, 
   PlotLabel -> "Break-even as function of rank r", 
   PlotLegends -> {"observed"}];

fit = LinearModelFit[{rvals, Log@dvals}\[Transpose], x, x];

fittedCoefs = CoefficientList[fit[x], x];
trueCoefs = {-EulerGamma, Log[Sqrt[2] + 2]};

nf[expr_] = NumberForm[N@expr, {4, 4}];
Print["coefficients: ", nf /@ fittedCoefs];

predictedPlot = 
  LogPlot[Exp@fit[r], {r, Min@rvals, Max@rvals}, PlotLegends -> {fit},
    PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[observedPlot, predictedPlot]
```

Comment: Related but not relevant for these cases:  [`RootApproximant`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RootApproximant.html)

Comment: I tried AskConstants (see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/70003/86543 and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/244369/86543 for examples) but I am not very experienced with it and it did not find either of the numbers in the list from their floating-point representation

Comment: Wolfram Alpha can also find possible closed forms but it did not find the right closed forms https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=0.5754319442167901 and https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1.2279386878150755%60

Comment: Are you sure about the `EulerGamma` one ? I found `N[EulerGamma , 10]=0.5772156649`

Comment: `N[Log[2 + Sqrt[2]], 10]=1.227947177`

Comment: For known constants you can also search https://oeis.org/search?q=0.5772156649&language=english&go=Search and also google the number

Comment: I asked ChatGPT 3.5 and it can also recognize the Euler number. The prompt: what is the exact closed for this floating point number: 0.5772156649

Comment: a quick search for opinions on reddit for this task via perplexity.ai also mentioned inverse symbolic calculator. From this link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3251082/any-good-alternatives-to-inverse-symbolic-calculator the site was closed but the original calculator is still accessible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `WolframAlpha` function to ask for possible closed forms of a number:

```
WolframAlpha["-0.5772156649 closed form", "DataRules"]
```

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

I was curious to see whether AskConstants could find the `Log[2+Sqrt[2]]` after providing the correct digits and it did ( here are some other examples using AskConstants (mentioned in my comment below the original post) https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/70003/86543 and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/244369/86543 )

[image]